# What is `change` event in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

What is `change` event in Angular 2? When is it dispatched and how can I use it?
I. e. what have I subscribed in following code via `(change)="update()"`?

http://plnkr.co/edit/mfoToOSLU6IU2zr0A8OB?p=preview

```
import {Component, View, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'inner-component',
  template: `
    <label><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="data.isSelected"> Selected</label>
  `
})
export class InnerComponent {
  data = { isSelected: false };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <p><inner-component (change)="update()"></inner-component></p>
    <p>The component was updated {{count}} times</p>
  `,
  directives: [InnerComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  count = 0;

  update() {
    ++this.count;
  }
}
```

PS: [Same question in Russian](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/542043/178988).

Comment: I am so surprised it works. Feels like a bug from angular.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's event bubbling: `change` occures on `input`, then bubbles by dom tree and gets handled on `inner-component` element. It can be checked by logging an event:

http://plnkr.co/edit/J8pRg3ow41PAqdMteKwg?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <p><inner-component (change)="update($event)"></inner-component></p>
    <p>The component was updated {{count}} times</p>
  `,
  directives: [InnerComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  count = 0;

  update($event) {
    console.log($event, $event.target, $event.currentTarget);
    ++this.count;
  }
}
```

Comment: So we actually can use (change) anywhere. That is really surprising me.

Answer (score 6):

The `change` event notifies you about a change happening in an input field. Since your inner component is not a native Angular component, you have to specifiy the event emitter yourself:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'inner-component',
  template: `
    <label><input type="checkbox" (change)="inputChange.emit($event)" [(ngModel)]="data.isSelected"> Selected</label>
  `
})
export class InnerComponent {
  @Output('change') inputChange = new EventEmitter();

  data = { isSelected: false };
}
```

And in your AppComponent you're now receiving the events:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <p><inner-component (change)="update($event)"></inner-component></p>
    <p>The component was updated {{count}} times</p>
  `,
  directives: [InnerComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  count = 0;

  update(event: any) {
    ++this.count;
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Comment: [My code](//plnkr.co/edit/mfoToOSLU6IU2zr0A8OB?p=preview) **is** working. If you open plunker, you'll see incrementing number of changes after clicking the checkbox. In [you code](//plnkr.co/edit/wCR7xS7ygEZijsN4B34W?p=preview) `change` is called **twice** on each checkbox click.

Comment: I found te reason. Thank you for working code with `(change)` on input - in my initial version it didn't work because I named EventEmitter as `change`.

Answer (score 0):

It is just an event emitter. For example if you take a look at Angular mat design's [source code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/select/select.ts) for `mat-select` you can see, but in this case, `selectionChange`

> ```
> @Output() readonly selectionChange: EventEmitter<MatSelectChange> =
>       new EventEmitter<MatSelectChange>();
> ```