# ngbDateTimepicker , how to get the change event in angular2

Tags: angular2-forms

I am using ngbDateTimePicker in my code and trying to get the value on change but I am not able to get it. I am trying click, ngmodelchange but nothing is working can anybody suggest me how to do this, please.

Below is my code

```
<div class="input-group" *ngSwitchCase="'date'" [attr.for]="dynamic.key" >
   <input class="form-control" [type]="'text'" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker"  ngModel   [attr.data-required]="dynamic.required"  [attr.for]="dynamic.key" [formControlName]="dynamic.fieldName" [id]="dynamic.fieldName" [name]="dynamic.fieldName" [attr.data-validation]="dynamic.validation" (click)="checkValidation(dynamic.fieldName,dynamic.validation,dynamic.required,dynamic.label);"  (blur)="checkValidation(dynamic.fieldName,dynamic.validation,dynamic.required,dynamic.label);" >
 <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="d1.toggle()">
       <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227838/what-is-change-event-in-angular-2

Comment: @ Anand Choudhary I am looking for ngbDatepicker's event that link above you mentioned is not related to it. I can't use any events on it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Men, your 'ngModelChange' works when you are simple using ngModel approach. When I want to use masked inputs to add "/", I need to implement my own ControlValueAccessor, that's fail at all.
Just a EventEmitter output property in ngb-datepicker, that can allow us to subscribe changes (like, 'valueChanges' of forms), it will help us a lot!
```

Comment: please suggest me some sober datepicker on angular2 which has events withpout ngmodel

Comment: As @raghav  suggests, you cannot access the datepicker model from your controller because the datepicker has its own private scope. for more info checkout link below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316937/how-to-bind-bootstrap-datepicker-element-with-angularjs-ng-model